# Jni java launcher work in c but not in c++

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, noclassdeffounderror

I have to make a program that launches a Java application in C++.

The first example in C works fine, it launches the jar perfectly in C. But when I run the same process in C++ I get an exception.

Here is the C code:

```
SetCurrentDirectoryA("..\\myJavaApp\\");
JavaVMInitArgs args;
int optionsLength = 4;
JavaVMOption options[optionsLength];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=path\\myJar.jar";

options[1].optionString = "-Xbootclasspath/p:.\\lib\\BootJar.jar";
options[2].optionString = "-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.protocol";
options[3].optionString = "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000";
args.options = options;
args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;
int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **) &env, &args);
if (ret < 0) {
    printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM %d ", ret);
} else {
    printf("\nJVM launched successfully");
}
UncaughtExceptionClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "mypackage/MyMainClass");
 if (UncaughtExceptionClass == NULL) {
    printf("\nClass not found.");
    (*jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm);
    return;
}

mainMethod = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, UncaughtExceptionClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
if (mainMethod == NULL) {
    printf("\nMethod not found.");
    (*jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm);
    return;
}

(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, UncaughtExceptionClass, mainMethod, NULL);

(*jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm);
```

and In C++:

```
SetCurrentDirectoryA(cmdval.c_str());
JavaVMInitArgs args;
JavaVMOption options[5];
std::cout << " number of argument " << nbargs << std::endl;

args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
args.nOptions = 5;
options[0].optionString = (char*) "-Djava.class.path=path\\myJar.jar";


options[1].optionString = (char*) "-Xbootclasspath/p:.\\lib\\BootJar.jar";
options[2].optionString = (char*) "-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.protocol";
options[3].optionString = (char*) "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000";
options[4].optionString = "-verbose:jni";

args.options = options;
args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;
int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **) &env, &args);
if (ret < 0)
{
    //        printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM %d ", ret);
}
else
{
    printf("\nJVM launched successfully\n");
} 
attachThread = (*jvm).AttachCurrentThread((void**) &env, NULL);

jclass mainClass =(*env).FindClass("mypackage/MyMainClass");
```

Here the exception I get in C++ :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage/MyMainClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.MyMainClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You seem to have a typo in -Djava.class.path=...

Comment: I edited it was a copy error

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `(*env)` with `env` and remove from the beginning of the bracket the `env`. For example replace:

```
FindClass(env, "mypackage/MyMainClass");
```

with:

```
FindClass("mypackage/MyMainClass");
```